# Change drush language

Tags: drush, i18n-l10n

Suddenly my drush has switched language and displays error messages in my native language, which is unfortunately not convenient if one tries to search for solutions on these errors.

Do you know how to switch the language of drush errors back to English?

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following string to `drushrc.php` worked for me with Drush 5.4:

```
$options['variables']['language_default']->language = 'en';
```

In my setup I placed `drushrc.php` into sites/default/drushrc.php, for other possible locations see documentation in `examples/example.drushrc.php` in Drush installation directory.

Comment: This works for me, whereas the solution by schnippy does not.

Answer (score 3):

Create (or modify) your [drushrc.php](http://drush.ws/examples/example.drushrc.php) file and add an option for your default language:

```
$override = array(
  'language_default' => (object) array(
    'language' => 'en',
  ),
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, putting that in ~/.drush/drushrc.php did not solve the problem. I still get localized errors.

Comment: did you try a 'drush cache-clear' command after updating the drushrc.php file?